# Why does Git create 'blank' conflicts?

Tags: git, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

Why would Git create a conflict that looks like this:

```
<<<<<<< mouseLabelCallbacks
const QMap<Qt::MouseButton, QString> TLabel::mMouseButtons = {
        {Qt::NoButton, QStringLiteral("NoButton")},           {Qt::LeftButton, QStringLiteral("LeftButton")},       {Qt::RightButton,     QStringLiteral("RightButton")},
        {Qt::MidButton, QStringLiteral("MidButton")},         {Qt::BackButton, QStringLiteral("BackButton")},       {Qt::ForwardButton,     QStringLiteral("ForwardButton")},
        {Qt::TaskButton, QStringLiteral("TaskButton")},       {Qt::ExtraButton4, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton4")},   {Qt::ExtraButton5,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton5")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton6, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton6")},   {Qt::ExtraButton7, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton7")},   {Qt::ExtraButton8,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton8")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton9, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton9")},   {Qt::ExtraButton10, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton10")}, {Qt::ExtraButton11,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton11")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton12, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton12")}, {Qt::ExtraButton13, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton13")}, {Qt::ExtraButton14,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton14")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton15, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton15")}, {Qt::ExtraButton16, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton16")}, {Qt::ExtraButton17,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton17")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton18, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton18")}, {Qt::ExtraButton19, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton19")}, {Qt::ExtraButton20,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton20")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton21, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton21")}, {Qt::ExtraButton22, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton22")}, {Qt::ExtraButton23,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton23")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton24, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton24")},

};


=======
>>>>>>> development
```

How is this in conflict when there's nothing between `===` and `>>>`?

Comment: check for `spaces` and `TAB` in your code.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you still have this conflict left to merge, and want to see what's going on, do this:

```
git config merge.conflictStyle diff3
git checkout -m path/to/conflicted/file.ext
```

(or, just:

```
git checkout -m --conflict=diff3 path/to/conflicted/file.ext
```

—the former sets up all future conflicts to be in `diff3` format).

Compare what's in it now to what was in it before.  Note the presence of the `|||||||` section:

```
<<<<<<< mouseLabelCallbacks
const QMap<Qt::MouseButton, QString> TLabel::mMouseButtons = {
        {Qt::NoButton, QStringLiteral("NoButton")},           {Qt::LeftButton, QStringLiteral("LeftButton")},       {Qt::RightButton,     QStringLiteral("RightButton")},
        {Qt::MidButton, QStringLiteral("MidButton")},         {Qt::BackButton, QStringLiteral("BackButton")},       {Qt::ForwardButton,     QStringLiteral("ForwardButton")},
        {Qt::TaskButton, QStringLiteral("TaskButton")},       {Qt::ExtraButton4, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton4")},   {Qt::ExtraButton5,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton5")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton6, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton6")},   {Qt::ExtraButton7, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton7")},   {Qt::ExtraButton8,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton8")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton9, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton9")},   {Qt::ExtraButton10, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton10")}, {Qt::ExtraButton11,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton11")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton12, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton12")}, {Qt::ExtraButton13, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton13")}, {Qt::ExtraButton14,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton14")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton15, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton15")}, {Qt::ExtraButton16, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton16")}, {Qt::ExtraButton17,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton17")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton18, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton18")}, {Qt::ExtraButton19, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton19")}, {Qt::ExtraButton20,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton20")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton21, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton21")}, {Qt::ExtraButton22, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton22")}, {Qt::ExtraButton23,     QStringLiteral("ExtraButton23")},
        {Qt::ExtraButton24, QStringLiteral("ExtraButton24")},

};

||||||| merged common ancestors
(something appears here, but I cannot guess what)
=======
>>>>>>> development
```

This tells you that in `>>>>>>> development`, the action was to *delete* the original "something", while in `<<<<<<< mouseLabelCallbacks`, the action was to *replace* the original "something" with the new section of code.

You must choose which of these resolutions is correct: delete-only, or delete-and-replace.  Usually it is the latter, but sometimes it's the former, or even a third thing.

Comment: it might be convenient to do a one-time diff-format choice, e.g.  diff3 with `git checkout -m --conflict=diff3`

Comment: That's the good answer. Using a 3 way merge tool is a need to better understand what was the intention of the other developers you must merge your code with.

Answer (score 0):

You / someone else may be edited and committed the file in different editor with different `file encoding`. That might have caused the issue.

Try to find out the file encoding format and change to correct format. There may be tools (may be Notepad++ , open file with Notepad++ to see the encoding). Then you can see the letters what git says about.